# Github: routing different project messages to different emails on my account

Tags: git, github

I've got multiple email addresses on my github account, and am running multiple projects.  Right now, all my messages (pull requests, code comments, etc) get routed to my "primary" email address (the one thats on my public profile).

I've configured the individual repos with the appropriate email addresses, but I was wondering if I could also tell github to route them to the specific addresses as well, so that I can keep things separate on my end?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In each github repository you can setup a hook to email changes on that repository. You can do that in the menu "Admin", then "Service Hooks", then "Email".

That way you can specify different notification mail address for different repositories.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub added [organization-level email routing](https://github.com/blog/1204-notifications-stars) in 2012.  You can modify your routing preferences in your [settings window](https://github.com/settings/notifications).  There's no way to configure email traffic for repositories that are in your top-level account.